# How to install extundelete on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, data-recovery, rm

I have removed some that are very important for me. They are not just images but text files and some other types of files. Based on my research I think the only way to recover most of them is to use `extundelete`. However, `extundelete` is a bit out-dated and cannot install it through `apt-get`. I am trying to compile the library manually but I keep getting errors for the lacking packages and am not able to find/install those packages easily. Can anyone help me install `extundelete`?

Comment: If you want to retrieve deleted files you shouldn't be working in  the same drive.

Comment: I know. I'm trying to do it from another hard drive

Comment: Testdisk and Photorec (installed and used in a live session or other installed system) come to mind as alternatives. But I don't know how to use either. Perhaps you can follow the tutorials: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step and http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step

Comment: @MichaelBay I am trying to install `extundelete`. Thanks for the links though ...

Comment: I know and if I coulod help you with that I would have posted an answer, nor comments. Instead I suggested what could be an alternative for retrieving the deleted files.

Comment: Please check this: http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS, extundelete is installed successfully.

```
sudo sh -c 'apt update && apt install extundelete'
```

Ubuntu says 'v0.2.4-1' is installed.

Please check your distribution version and package update.

ps: please do not install extundelete on same partition which deleted file was in. Boot with other media like live cd. I'm afraid new package list cache, list, extundelete related files may overwrite your deleted files.

Answer (score 0):

> Solution :

Install extundelete
Installing extundelete package on **Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus)** is as easy as running the following command on terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install extundelete
```

> Solution 2 :

```
sudo apt-get update -y

sudo apt-get install -y extundelete
```

**Leave A Like, Or Comment.**

Answer (score -1):

I also encountered this problem as you described when I installed **extundelete** on ubuntu 16.04, like the following:

```
sudo apt-get install package_name
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package package_name
```

Later I found that is because the installation manner you chosen is out of date and not suitable for Ubuntu 16.04. Here you may refer to this tutorial [Troubleshooting “E: Unable to locate package” Error on Ubuntu](https://itsfoss.com/unable-to-locate-package-error-ubuntu/). Actually, it is so easy to install **extundelete** with apt-get on Ubuntu 16.04.

You just need:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install extundelete
```

Please refer to the website [extundelete_0.2.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/extundelete_0.2.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb.html) and get more details. Last but not least, it is necessary to install the utility **extundelete** before you write data on your computer. Then the **extundelete** can help you recover your important data.